# Magento System error on change currency

Tags: php, magento

When I want to change currency in

> **magneto system > configuration > change currency**

I get an error

The error that I get is:

Invalid config field backed model:

> **xmlconnect/adminhtml_system_config_backend_currency_default**

Trace:

```
#0 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
#1 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
#4 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
#5 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/__default.php(14015): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
#6 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/__default.php(18399): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#7 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/__default.php(17933): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/includes/src/__default.php(20705): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /mnt/web2/d1/07/51763507/htdocs/gelecto.nl/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: What if they tell us about your version of Magento? before the error occurs you installed a module or you modified something?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you have allready looked at [magento how to set default language and currency](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-default-language-and-currency.html)

1. In admin panel, go to `Admin > System > Configuration > Currency Set up`.
2. Select currency that you want to be default from your base currency drop down.
3. Select the same currency in the **Default Display Currency drop down** and from the Allowed Currencies list.
4. Click Save Config.
5. The front-end display currency should be different if you check out your site.